# Capybara: How To Assert A Given Number of Elements Exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, capybara, integration-testing

I've upgraded my whole stack from a Rails 3.0 based project to 3.1. I have specs passing but my features are now being a bit picky. The issue I'm currently having is this step:

```
Then /^I should see (\d+) menu item(?:s)? within "([^"]*)"$/ do |count, selector|
  page.find(:css, selector, :count => count.to_i)
end
```

And in the feature itself, I might put:

```
Then I should see 5 menu items within "tr#menu_item_row"
```

The message I get is:

```
Then I should see 5 menu items within "tr#menu_item_row"                                      # features/step_definitions/admin_menu_steps.rb:1
  Ambiguous match, found 5 elements matching css "tr#menu_item_row" (Capybara::Ambiguous)
  ./features/step_definitions/admin_menu_steps.rb:2:in `/^I should see (\d+) menu item(?:s)? within "([^"]*)"$/'
  features/admin_menu.feature:30:in `Then I should see 5 menu items within "tr#menu_item_row"'
```

As far as I can tell, the 5 elements match the 5 that were actually found. Did I write this code wrong or has something major changed? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to check 5 elements you shouldn't use `#find` as by default since Capybara 2.0 this method always throws an exception if it finds more or less than one element. This was an intentional and (I believe) a good change.

To assert that 5 elements are present an appropriate method is a rspec matcher:

```
expect(page).to have_css(selector, count: count.to_i)
```

I don't recommend [to set `match` to `prefer_exact`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#strategy) as recommended by @fontno as in most of situations you want Capybara to throw an exception if `find` finds more than one element.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a change between versions 1.x and 2.x. You can look at all the changes in the [capybara upgrade guide](http://techblog.fundinggates.com/blog/2012/08/capybara-2-0-upgrade-guide/) and this [blog post](http://www.elabs.se/blog/60-introducing-capybara-2-1).

The `find` method now raises an `ambiguous match` error if more than one element is found. If you only have a few examples you could do something like this

```
Then /^I should see (\d+) menu item(?:s)? within "([^"]*)"$/ do |count, selector|
  page.find(:css, selector, :count => count.to_i, match: prefer_exact)
end
```

or if you have many examples like this you could change the capybara configuration for backwards compatability, something like this

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.match = :prefer_exact
  config.ignore_hidden_elements = false
end
```

You may have to modify this to get it working but this is the general idea. See the links I mention above, its all in there. Hope this sets you in the right direction

Comment: `:prefer_exact` can be considered a bad practice as you can see in blog post you linked to and was added in Capybara 2.1 as a lot of people said that they need it for backwards compatability with their code written for 1.x. I think it's a bad idea to advice to use it.

Comment: so because I referenced and linked to the article I deserve a down vote? I was simply telling the questioner why this happened and what could be done about it. I didn't tell the questioner they shouldn't update the feature and only do it this way. Just pointing it out as the question was "did something change?"

Comment: Upvoting because it actually focused my attention on the difference between the `match` settings.